# how to recyclerview scroll on SlideUpPanelLayout?

Tags: android

```
<com.tapasya.customsetting.customWidget.SlidingUpPanelLayout
        xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/slidingUp_notfication"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="top"
        sothree:umanoDragView="@+id/notificationRV_notification"
        sothree:umanoOverlay="true"
        sothree:umanoPanelHeight="20dp"
        sothree:umanoParalaxOffset="0dp"
        sothree:umanoShadowHeight="0dp"
        >

        <!--Must use two child -->

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="21dp"
            />

        <include layout="@layout/notification_widget"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            />


</com.tapasya.customsetting.customWidget.SlidingUpPanelLayout>
```

In notification_widget.layout, we are use recyclerview but that list not drag down .how to drag down recyclerview on SlideUpPanel

Comment: maybe you need to behavior like material bottom sheet menu?

Comment: ty for ur suggestions  but its not satisfy for me

Comment: ty sir for ur suggestions

Comment: please any budy help for this  critical question